# Application of maximum modulus to find bound

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm given a function $f(z)$ continuous in the strip $\{z:0 \leq \operatorname{Re}(z) \leq 1\}$ and holomorphic in its interior, and the following bounds in the strip: $$|f(iy)| \leq 1$$ $$|f(1+iy) \leq 1$$ $$|f(x+iy)| \leq Ce^{|y|}$$ for some constant C.  I want to prove that $|f| \leq 1$ everywhere on the strip.

I'm given the hint to use the function $g(z)=f(z)e^{\epsilon z^2}$ on the rectangle $[0,1] \times [-iR,iR]$ (to apply the maximum modulus principle).

However, I'm stuck on this problem.  I assume that we need to try to show that $|g(z)| \leq e^{\epsilon z^2}$, but the bounds I'm finding don't seem to give me this.

The bounds I got were: $e^{|y|} \leq e^R$ and $|e^{\epsilon z^2}| \leq e^{\epsilon}e^{\epsilon R^2}$ by applying max modulus (the former is obvious, the latter is from calculating $z^2$ for $iR$ with $iR+1$ and comparing).  With this, $|g(z)| \leq Ce^Re^{\epsilon}e^{\epsilon R^2}$, which doesn't give me anything.  So either my bounds are wrong, or I'm approaching the problem in the wrong way.

This is the first time I've seen this kind of problem, so I'm not sure how to approach it.  I'd appreciate it if anyone could lead me into the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $g(z) =f(z) e^{\varepsilon z^2} $ where $\varepsilon >0 .$ The function $g$ has following properties:

1. $g$ is continuous in the strip $\{z:0\leqslant \mbox{Re}(z)\leqslant 1\}$ and holomorphic in its interior
2. $|g(it)| =|f(it)||e^{\varepsilon (it)^2} | =|f(it)|e^{-\varepsilon t^2} \leqslant 1$

   $|g(1+it)| =|f(it)||e^{\varepsilon (1+it)^2} | =|f(it)|e^{\varepsilon (1- t^2)} \leqslant e^{\varepsilon}$
3. $g$ is bounded on the set $\{z:0\leqslant \mbox{Re}(z)\leqslant 1\} .$

Hence from Hadamard three-lines theorem we obtain that $$|g(z)|\leqslant e^{\varepsilon} $$ in the strip $\{z:0\leqslant \mbox{Re}(z)\leqslant 1\}.$ Therefore $$|f(z)|\leqslant e^{\varepsilon (1-x^2 -y^2)}$$ in the strip $\{z:0\leqslant \mbox{Re}(z)\leqslant 1\}.$

Now letting $\varepsilon \to 0$ we otain $$|f(z)|\leqslant 1 $$ in the strip $\{z:0\leqslant \mbox{Re}(z)\leqslant 1\}.$

Comment: I don't believe we have covered the three-lines theorem, but after looking at your answer and the theorem, I can see how the problem is meant to be approached.  Thanks for the help